# Not every holomorphic function $f$ can be written as $f(z)=e^{g(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Problem:** Show that not every holomorphic function $f:\Bbb C-\{0\}\to\Bbb C-\{0\}$ can be written as
>   $$f(z)=e^{g(z)}$$
>   for some holomorphic function $g:\Bbb C-\{0\}\to\Bbb C$.

I tried to arrive at a contradiction by supposing
$$e^{g(z)}=\frac{1}{z}$$
for some $g$. We would have $\int_\gamma e^{g(z)}dz=2\pi i$ over the unit circle, so it would be sufficient to show that $e^{g(z)}$ extends to a holomorphic function on $\Bbb C$, but I am not sure if we can do this.

Comment: Why $\frac1z$? What $g$ could you take for $f(z)=z$?

Comment: Consider  $g:\mathbb C^*\to \mathbb C$, compose with $exp:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C^*$ and apply the  fundamental group $\pi_1$. You may take $fz)=\frac 1z$ or more simply $f(z)=z$, as suggested by @Hagen . You will then have $\pi_1(f)=Id_{\mathbb Z}:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$, which cannot be factored as $\mathbb Z  \to 0\to \mathbb Z $

Answer (score 2):

If there is a holomorphic $g:\mathbb{C}^*\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $e^{g(z)}=z$ then $1=g'(z)e^{g(z)}=g'(z)z$. Thus,
$$0=\int_{C^+(0,1)}g'(z)dz=\int_{C^+(0,1)}\frac{dz}{z}=2\pi i$$
Which is absurd.